# how to change nginx site url

Tags: nginx, gitlab

My ngix site config file (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/) is given below. Right now I can access this site by going to `localhost` but I would like to know how to change the site url to `localhost/gitlab`. I need `localhost` reserved for a different website.

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
#  listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name localhost;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** GitLab now has better support for relative URLs and dedicated documentation:

- Source installations http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html
- Omnibus packages https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-a-relative-url-for-gitlab

---

You want to move GitLab in a relative url. Bear in mind that except for the nginx config, you must also change the url in 3 other places. See the directions in `gitlab.yml`:

```
# Uncomment and customize the last line to run in a non-root path
# WARNING: This feature is known to work, but unsupported
# Note that three settings need to be changed for this to work.
# 1) In your application.rb file: config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
# 2) In your gitlab.yml file: relative_url_root: /gitlab
# 3) In your unicorn.rb: ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
```

All these configs are under `/home/git/gitlab/config`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these answers have been successful for OP, but for me nothing worked at all :

- trafficking with `location` ...
- Uncommenting files with relative URL, etc .

I did find a "tweak" which both elegant and concise, but requires you to have a registered domain name (not suitable for local IPs `192.168.0.x`) :

1. Set up a DNS A Zone pointing to your server's IP (the same as your main domain) : 
   `gitlab.mydomain.me`.
2. Update `server_name mydomain.me` to `server_name gitlab.mydomain.me;` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab`.
3. Restart nginx : `sudo service nginx restart`.

You now have a working gitlab subdomain, and your "main" domain is free.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're not actually changing the site name, you're moving it to a sub-directory, so you can easily change the

```
location / { ... }
```

to be a sub directory

```
location /gitlab { ... }
```

and reload nginx then it should work, but you need to make sure that if the website doesn't create relative URL's then you need to change it's config so it doesn't create a link that would move you outside the `/gitlab` directory.